# VBA How to loop through columns

Tags: excel, vba

This code adds a spinner button in each row. How could I write it to add a spinner button in each column... Lets say I want to add a spinner button in A1, B1, C1... G1.

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 7
    ActiveSheet.Spinners.Add(Range("A" & i).Left, Range("A" & i).Top, 69.5, 20).Select
Next
```

Comment: Change the ranges to go across instead of down.

Comment: For tasks like this, `Cells(rowNumber, colNumber)` is easier to work with than `Range()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you loop over the elements of a range, it does not matterr if you traverse columns or rows.  Here is a `Button` example:

```
Sub BoxAdder()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, bt As Button, s As Shape
    Set rng = Range("A1:G1")

    For Each r In rng
        ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(94.5, 75.75, 51, 27.75).Select
        Set bt = Selection
        bt.Characters.Text = r.Address(0, 0)
        Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Selection.Name)
        With s
            .Top = r.Top
            .Left = r.Left
            .Width = r.Width
            .Height = r.Height
        End With
    Next r
End Sub
```

The code places buttons on cells A1, B1, C1, D1, E1. F1, and G1 sequentially.  To place the buttons down a column, just change:

```
Set rng = Range("A1:G1")
```

to:

```
Set rng = Range("A1:A4")
```

Note that for the purposes of moving and sizing, I treat each `Button` as a `Shape`.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question! Although I ended up using                                               
  ```For i = 1 To 7
        ActiveSheet.Spinners.Add(Cells(1, i).Left, Cells(1, i).Top, 69.5, 20).Select
  Next ```